# Position fixed with not obeying max-width container parent

Tags: css

I am trying to make horizontal navigation bar and right now my div navigation bar doesn't use max-width: 1200px which is set on `<body>` so my unordered list isn't floated to the right of the screen. Adding width: 100% or inherit to navigation does not help, width 100% is way more than my max-width.

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
}
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  margin: 1% 4% 2%;
  padding: 1rem;
}
#navigation {
  position: fixed;
}
#navigation ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#navigation li {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Projects</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: May this be what you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/nkoabk5h/

Comment: Will this change work for you? `#navigation li {
  float: left;
}`

Comment: Maybe try this? https://jsfiddle.net/matt9388/1vyruezr/1/  I added width:100%; to your #nav div, and moved your padding down to the ul element.  The padding was causing your div to go off the screen when set at 100%.

Comment: Aero - your navigation is 200 px it isnt the max-width, @Matt You can try resizing your window it goes well beyond max-width 1200px so this doesn't work I tried it with my navigation and width 100% made it actuall 1980px instead of 1200px at max.

Comment: yep your right.  Try moving your max-width to your #navigation element.   Here's an updated fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/matt9388/1vyruezr/2/  I think maybe the position fixed makes that div ignore the parent elements max-width.

Comment: @Matt alright cheers for help it works now you could add it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I moved your max-width to your #navigation element, and set it to 100% width.
Also I moved your padding down to your ul element.

Here's the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matt9388/1vyruezr/2).

```
#navigation {
  position: fixed;
  max-width:1200px;
  width:100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#navigation ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

I think maybe the position fixed makes the div ignore the parent elements max-width